# "Your answer couldn't be submitted because: Title cannot be longer than 150 characters"

Tags: bug, edits, asking-questions, title, error-message

When editing a question's title, the following error message should say "question" and not "answer":

> Oops! Your **answer** couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Title cannot be longer than 150 characters

[image: question submit page with error message]

Comment: What is the bug? Titles are limited to 150 characters by design, but it hasn't always been that way. Titles that existed in a longer format already when the change was implemented were grandfathered in due to how databases work. If you want to edit such a post you need to shorten the title.

Comment: @TylerH, since when do *answers* have titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has since been fixed. Both error messages at the top and at the bottom of the page now read:

> Your ***question*** couldn't be submitted.

As shown in the screenshot:

[image: Your question couldn't be submitted error message]

Using the edit dialogue the message says:

> Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.

[image: Your edit couldn't be submitted error message]